# Create a recurring Google Calendar event every Tues-Fri every week

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to make a Google Calendar event that repeats every day except for Mondays (and weekends). Is there a way to do this? I know I could do four different weekly events, but is there a way to do just one event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done using the **Custom Recurrence** feature.

- Create your event as usual.
- Select the dropdown for `doesn't repeat`

[image: doesn't repeat]

- Select "Custom" (the last choice in the list.

[image: custom]

- A "Custom Recurrence" popup is displayed.

  - Select "Repeat every one week"
  - Check the event days (Tues, Wed, Thurs & Fri)
  - Select an "Ends" parameter

[image: Recurrence]